# Role of navigator.serviceWorker.controller in serviceWorker.js of Create React App

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, service-worker

Below is an excerpt of **serviceWorker.js** generated by CRA.

What is the point of having `if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller)` inside 
`if (installingWorker.state === 'installed')`?

The new service worker has been successfully installed at this stage. Does the 'else' part handle the scenario in which no previous service worker has been installed yet?

```
navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
              // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
              // content until all client tabs are closed.
              console.log(
                'New content is available and will be used when all ' +
                  'tabs for this page are closed.'
              );

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`navigator.serviceWorker.controller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/controller) will be set to a truthy value (a [`ServiceWorker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker) object) if the current page is under the control of a service worker.

If this is the first time a service worker's been registered whose `scope` encompasses the current page's URL, then `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` will not be set (*unless* the service worker itself calls `clients.claim()`).

If this is a subsequent visit to a page that is under the registered service worker's `scope`, then `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` will be set, and the page will be under the service worker's control.